# Microsoft Teams: How can I get Chat ID of the direct conversation between Bot<->User?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.
Now we are implementing expiration date for all messages in database to wipe them after some period of time.
If we need to restore some messages we're using [protected api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).

> /* Get Direct Messages */
>
> messages = graphClient.chats(chatId).messages().buildRequest().get();

But there's a problem with direct chats we can't find the ChatID anywhere, we only have ConversationId.
If we look closer to ChatID we can see that we can actually generate it:

> /* Example Chat ID: */
>
> String chatId =
> "19:f9b63c6a-c731-4a52-8203-60d886978f9a_5a287066-43c0-40b0-8e39-d8779e37ae38@unq.gbl.spaces"

We can generate it using User AADID and Bot AADID like this:

> String chatId = "19:" + UserAADID + "_" + BotAADID + "@unq.gbl.spaces"

Is this a good way to generate ChatIDs and can we just hardcode these parameters: "19:", "@unq.gbl.spaces" ?
And if not then **how can we get a ChatID of a direct conversation**?

We are using Java Bot Framework and Java Graph SDK (com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:3.7.0)

Comment: You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages#retrieve-the-conversation-chatid) to retrieve the conversation chat id.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Thanks. Is there non beta way ? We had issues with beta before because it might be changed anytime.

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages#retrieve-the-conversation-chatid) and replace beta with v1.0.